# How do you change the customer invoice template in Magento 1.6

Tags: magento

How do you change the customer invoice template in Magento 1.6? We want to remove the area where it tells the customer about a tracking number and change some of the wording the email produces.

An example of the email we want to edit can be found here: http://deadlydash.com/magento.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**System > Transactional Emails > Add Template**

- Select "New Invoice"
- Load Template
- Edit as desired
- Do the same for guest invoice template as well (if appropriate).

**System > Configuration > Sales Emails**

- Set the templates you've just created as the templates to use for these emails.